# multiple threads accessing array

Tags: java, android

I am trying to use arrayList across multiple threads in which 2 threads add elements to it and one thread just retrieve the first elements. I know I can use the syncronizedList but I wanted to see if this impleentation is right. Basically  I add all my array manipulation in a synhcronized method

```
public void synchronized addElem(String str){
  String s = str.trim();
  myArray.add(s);
 }
```

Is this ok?

Comment: This will lock the object that contains addElem() while you add data to the array.

Comment: Adding to the answers below; once you familiarize yourself with this, check out [`ReentrantReadWriteLock`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReentrantReadWriteLock.html). In higher performance situations a read-write lock is a basic tool that you can instead of the vanilla mutex that `synchronized` uses. Read-write locks allow multiple threads to read at once but only one thread to write (and no reads during writes), which can give much higher throughput in situations where concurrent reads can be done without harm.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is not enough to synchronize writing, you need to synchronize reading as well. Otherwise, a read that happens concurrently with a  write may return inconsistent data, or trigger exceptions:

```
public synchronized String getFirst() {
    if (myArray.size() != 0)
        return myArray.get(0);
    return null;
}
```

You could also use `Collections.synchronizedList`

```
List<String> syncList = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<String>());
```

Answer (score 3):

No.  You'd need to synchronize on ALL times you access the list, as well as make sure you don't pass any references to it elsewhere.  That's why the synchronized classes exist-  to save you the effort.  This is part of the answer, but not sufficient.

Answer (score 2):

You can also used a synchronized block as `synchronized(myArray) { // logic}`. This is preferred over a synchronized method if your method is too long and will hold up the required object for too long. `synchronized` block, on the other hand, will keep the object locked only as long as it is needed.